# Weird behavior when adding two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm adding two cv2 images `height * width * 3 pixels` (to calculate average).

The problem is that a raw image differs from when I add it to an empty numpy array initialized to zero:

```
base = np.zeros((960, 1280, 3), dtype = np.int64)
frame = cv2.read()[1] # I know frames are coming in
imshow(frame)
```

[image]

```
imshow((base+frame))
```

[image]

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. My only lead is that the numpy addition operator is performing a different form of elementwise addition that what I expect it to. However, this was not the case once I reshaped the two images into row vectors. So I'm really stuck. Any ideas?

ps. if you are wondering what these images are of – a rig for collecting movement data for fruit flies.

Comment: I don't think `cv2.read()` will return an array with `dtype=int64`. Maybe print out the dtype of both `base+frame` and `frame` to see whether they are different.

Comment: that must be it. I'll try it and get back.

Comment: `cv2.read()` uses `uint8`. When I make `base` a `uint8` array it works. Thank you so much for noticing this. This wasn't in my hypothesis space because with python you don't usually deal with types. I guess this was my coming of age story as a numpy developer.